# How to correctly add fragments on Android Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, fragment

friends. Currently, I am developing an application on Android Kotlin. My application consists of 5 different fragments. Navigation between fragments occurs using botton navigation view in MainActivity class. All fragments should be created once ( to save state ) except one fragment. Only one fragment should be re-created every time I navigate to that fragment. How can I realize that kind of logic?

Answer (score 0):

do You already know about Jetpack Navigation...
If you wnat switch Between fragmnet this is the best way.
use these links

[https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation](https://medium.com/@prasannajeet/using-the-navigation-architecture-component-in-android-jetpack-kotlin-48d4167ec9e5)

[example of Jetpack Navigation for kotlin](https://medium.com/@prasannajeet/using-the-navigation-architecture-component-in-android-jetpack-kotlin-48d4167ec9e5)